# Use 的 to make a connection

Tags: grammar, vocabulary, sentence-structure

你要靠你自己的能力来学习中文。

你要靠你自己的能力来努力的学习中文。

The first one seemed to be correct.  But not sure about the second one if the 努力 was added correctly.

Any comments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The '的' in '自己的' is a possessive marker. "自己" = "oneself"; "自己的" = "onself's"

Some people use 的 and 地 interchangeably in the adverb role. The second 的 in the second sentence functions the same as 地 as an adverb marker

你要靠你自己的能力来学习中文。

你要靠你自己的能力来努力(的/ 地)学习中文。

The term '努力' itself can function as an adverb. "你要靠你自己的能力去努力学习中文。" would be a cleaner sentence

努力地 is also an adverb, but it emphasizes the manner of the action.

*I personally never use 的 instead of 地 to mark an adverb.*

*Side note: I changed 来努力 to 去努力. Both are grammatical but '靠你自己的能力来' emphasizes 'with (自己的能力)' and '力去努力学习中文' emphasizes 'to (学习中文)'*

Comment: "Some people use 的 and 地 interchangeably" just to clarify, they are WRONG to do so, right?

Comment: I speak Cantonese, writing in Standard Written Chinese so, I never use  '的 instead of 地'  in adverb role,  however, it is listed in some dictionaries. Maybe it is a regional practice

Comment: @小奥利奥 I suspect because both 的 and 地 are pronounced as / dì/ in Mandarin. People got confused and some started to use 的 instead of 地. With enough people doing that, 的 gained the function of being a variant of 地

Comment: In this case, it's actually pronounced as 'de', the neutral tone.

Comment: For a reason I can’t explain.  But in these sentences, i wanted to emphasizes 'with (自己的能力)' .